# Laravel Eloquent where between two dates are null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get values between two dates. I have some data between dates but it returns empty.

```
$oneMonthAgo = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime('-1 month'));
$thisMonth = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime('0 month'));
$nextMonth = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime('+1 month'));


$cezalar = DB::table('cezalar')
    ->where('ceza_tarih', '>=', $oneMonthAgo)
    ->where('ceza_tarih', '<', $thisMonth)
    ->get();

return $cezalar;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the query log, to see what SQL gets generated?

Comment: No, where do i look?

Comment: You could try and install the laravel debug bar, by the brilliant barryvhd : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```php
$thisMonth = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();

$oneMonthAgo = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth();

$dateRange = [$oneMonthAgo, $thisMonth];

$cezalar = DB::table('cezalar')->whereBetween('ceza_tarih', $dateRange)->get();
```

Check [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), which is available out of the box, in `Laravel`.

Answer (score 0):

first note : you are using "query builder" not eloquent,

and if you want to get one month ago date you should use something like this :

`$oneMonthAgo = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('-1 month'));`

I have checked it in my own app, and it is working...